# How to add NAs for missing combinations of variables to a long-format data.frame in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following time series:

```
dat = data.frame(
  years = c(c(2010:2005), 2010:2005),
  var   = c(rep('var1', 6), rep('var2', 6)),
  val   = rnorm(12)
)

dat = dat[-c(2,3, 7),]

#    years  var        val
# 1   2005 var1 -1.4450211
# 4   2008 var1  0.6735435
# 5   2009 var1 -0.1014753
# 6   2010 var1 -0.9275398
# 8   2006 var2 -1.0999713
# 9   2007 var2  0.1295319
# 10  2008 var2 -0.1086212
# 11  2009 var2  1.6091967
# 12  2010 var2  0.5937776
```

How can I get to this in a smart way:

```
2005 var1 -1.4450211
2006 var1  NA
2007 var1  NA
2008 var1  0.6735435
2009 var1 -0.1014753
2010 var1 -0.9275398
2005 var2  NA
2006 var2 -1.0999713
2007 var2  0.1295319
2008 var2 -0.1086212
2009 var2  1.6091967
2010 var2  0.5937776
```

My actual data set is very large and I also have more variables, so trying to implement this with nested for loops is really ugly and slow. There must be a better solution but I just cant seem to find it.

Bonus: I need this to get a line plot out of ggplot that does not connect years with missing data in between, if you know another solution that would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: is nan always on the same position?

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense. It doesn't match input values.

Comment: sorry, was a bit sloppy copy and pasting the example, fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat)`, specify the 'key' columns, cross join with unique elements of 'years' and 'var', and then `order` the rows by 'var', 'years'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(dat, key= c('years', 'var'))[CJ(years, var, unique=TRUE)][order(var,years)]
```